# Finding the nearest neighbour, from an atom within a crystal

Tags: crystal-structure, software

Is there any software can give me the information of nearest neighbour, nest nearest neighbour,....(and their distance) from an atom within a crystal (described by a .cif file)? Perhaps some visualization software like VESTA?

Answer (score 4):

I don't use VESTA and there are probably a few tools that can do this.

My suggestion would be to use the open source Python package [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/) or "Atomic Simulation Environment." developed in part by the group of [Karsten W. Jacobsen](http://www.fysik.dtu.dk/english/Research/CAMD/Research/Atomic-scale-materials-design).

There are several algorithms available for generating neighbor lists and iterating through them:
https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/neighborlist.html

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
# get neighbors of atom 42
indices, offsets = nl.get_neighbors(42)
for i, offset in zip(indices, offsets):
    print(atoms.positions[i] + dot(offset, atoms.get_cell()))
```

Comment: I checked ASE, but that seems require LINUX. I have only WINDOWS system

Comment: ASE requires Python (e.g., [ASE install instructions](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/install.html) ) and certainly Python and ASE can be installed on Windows: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: I have got Pythod under windows....so how should I proceed to install ASE? get Cywin? I have also got it......

Comment: As indicated in my comment above, if you have Python installed, you can [install ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/install.html) using `pip install --upgrade --user ase`

Comment: Where should I run this pip command? Under Python or under window command? or under Cywin? I have tried them all but none successed.

Comment: I don't use Windows, so I'm not a good person to ask. I'd find a Python-specific forum (e.g., Python on Windows) and ask there. On Mac or Linux, you can simply run `pip` from the command-line. Heck, you might want to ask the [ASE forums](https://listserv.fysik.dtu.dk/mailman/listinfo/ase-users).